# AngularJS: jQuery functions in jqLite

Tags: angularjs

I just want to ask for some help with converting the following code from jQuery to jqLite (angular jQuery):

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
          #some funcs
    }, 100)
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {

    // your code here

});
```

Comment: What about set timeout?

Comment: setTimeout :) What do you mean by saying "I need this setTimeout rewrited on jqLite". There is no anything like setTimeout in jqLite. There is service $timeout in AngularJS. It provides api for unit tests (testable) and $timeout service starts digest loop after timeout callack is fired.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to that question depends on the context and use case and how it relates to the AngularJS framework and the phases of the app.

To start something in the AngularJS run phase:

```
app.run(function($timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
        //Startup code
    },100);
});
```

To start something in an AngularJS service:

```
app.service("something", function($timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
        //Startup code
    },100);
});
```

Of course the `$timeout` may not be necessary.

Or to start third-party code before bootstrapping AngularJS:

```
angular.element(function() {
    //Third-party startup code
    angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
});
```

The choice really depends on the context and how the third-party code interacts with the AngularJS framework.